# Is there any charge at complete rest relative to us?

Tags: electrostatics

Electrostatic branch deals with charge in rest.But the question is that is any charge at rest? As for as my knowledge recalls I haven't heard or read even a single example whrere in practicle purpose charge is at rest relative to us.

Comment: You have not heard of [static electricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_electricity)?

Answer (score 0):

> is that is any charge at rest?

No, of course not.  A charge at rest in some coordinate system is not at rest in a relatively moving coordinate system.

Does this invalidate electrostatics?  Of course not.  Can you think of the reason why?

---

Update:  preserving the comments:

[image]

Comment: cause we can get it in rest forour coordinate system

Comment: @PakistanZindabad, we first study *idealizations* (such as electrostatics) in physics in order to gain insight and obtain results that turn out to be astoundingly useful even in the case that, e.g., the system of charges is only *approximately* static (over some time within some region etc.).  As an analogy, in electrical engineering, we study *linear, time invariant* circuits and systems (a lot) but no circuit or system is, in practice, genuinely linear and time invariant.  But the theory of linear time invariant systems is nonetheless *enormously* useful!